# Rocket Chat in Docker Desktop

Tags: rocket.chat

I have installed rocket chat server on docker desktop but after setting it up i cant access the server ip address to client pc. Anyone who can help.

I already check all the firewall settings and enable port 3000 but still the issue persist.

The server ip can be ping also via client.